# aws lambda s3 function isn't called inside alexa skills kit

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a skill for Amazon Echo that will call a JSON file from AWS S3. When I call the code from s3 basic get function it works. And the Amazon Alexa code works on its own.

But when I call them together the function gets skipped. So for the following code the console gets called before and after `s3.getObject()`. But the middle one gets skipped. I do not understand why.

I also checked whether s3 was being called, and it is.

```
let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

function callS3() {
    console.log('loading S3 function');
    var myData = [];

    const params = {
        Bucket: 'cvo-echo',
        Key: 'data.json'
    };
    console.log("trying to get s3");
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error in s3 get: \n' + err);
            //const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}.
            // Make sure they exist and your bucket is in same region as this function.
            //console.log(message);
        } else {
            console.log('CONTENT TYPE: ', data.ContentType);
            console.log('Data body: \n' + data.Body.toString());
            myData = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString());
            console.log('myData.length = ' + myData.length);
        }
        console.log('myData >> ' + myData);
    });

    console.log('finished callS3() func');
    return myData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a control flow issue, I've worked with amazons sdk before and was running into similar issues. Try implementing [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) within your code to have a better control of what happens when. This way methods won't skip.

UPDATE: adding some code examples of what you could do.

```
function callS3(callback) {
    console.log('loading S3 function');
    var myData = [];

    const params = {
        Bucket: 'cvo-echo',
        Key: 'data.json'
    };
    console.log("trying to get s3");
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error in s3 get: \n' + err);
            //const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}.
            // Make sure they exist and your bucket is in same region as this function.
            //console.log(message);

            callback(err,null);//callback the error.
        } else {
            console.log('CONTENT TYPE: ', data.ContentType);
            console.log('Data body: \n' + data.Body.toString());
            myData = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString());
            console.log('myData.length = ' + myData.length);

            console.log('myData >> ' + myData);
            console.log('finished callS3() func');

            //Include the callback inside of the S3 call to make sure this function returns until the S3 call completes.
            callback(null,myData); // first element is an error and second is your data, first element is null if no error ocurred.
        }
    });

}

/*
This MIGHT work without async but just in case you can read more about 
async.waterfall where functions pass down values to the next function.
*/

async.waterfall([
    callS3()//you can include more functions here, the callback from the last function will be available for the next.
    //myNextFunction()
],function(err,myData){
    //you can use myData here.
})
```

Comment: I tried using async however I do not think I did it properly. here is how I tried it: [s3 with async](http://pastebin.com/aGZLq4Xt)

Comment: You are trying to mix sync functions with async functions and that is not going to work, you need to get rid of your return statement and instead get that value using callbacks. So in the end you will basically replace return myData with callback(myData). I'm currently out right now but I will update my answer later. Hopefully this gives you some insight of how to resolve your issue.

Comment: @ManjurKhan I have updated my answer with code sample.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I couldnt get it to work still, so I am currently using python to get the information from s3 which works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timing issue. Here is an example of loading a JSON file from an S3 share when a session is started.

```
function onLaunch(launchRequest, session, callback) {
    var sBucket = "your-bucket-name";
    var sFile = "data.json";
    var params = {Bucket: sBucket, Key: sFile};
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var s3file = s3.getObject(params)

    new AWS.S3().getObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            var json = JSON.parse(new Buffer(data.Body).toString("utf8"));
            for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                 console.log("name:" + json[i].name + ", age:" + json[i].age);
            }                
            getWelcomeResponse(callback);                
        } else {
            console.log(err.toString());
        }
    });        
}
```